# Vue watch method not filtering object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The filter option does not seem to be working in a Vue watched function. The below should remove the E: object, but it does not remove anything. I have confirmed the filter code is executing, returning `false` for the E: object, and `true` for everything else (expected). However, the item remains in the array.

The object passed to the component via prop:

```
[
    {
        "fs": "C:",
        "type": "NTFS",
        "size": 273649844224,
        "used": 265129050112,
        "use": 96.88624192856284,
        "mount": "C:"
    },
    {
        "fs": "D:",
        "type": "NTFS",
        "size": 1000202039296,
        "used": 879919800320,
        "use": 87.97420578539696,
        "mount": "D:"
    },
    {
        "fs": "E:",
        "type": "NTFS",
        "size": 524283904,
        "used": 35745792,
        "use": 6.818022015796998,
        "mount": "E:"
    },
    {
        "fs": "F:",
        "type": "NTFS",
        "size": 250058108928,
        "used": 193818132480,
        "use": 77.50923707729336,
        "mount": "F:"
    },
    {
        "fs": "G:",
        "type": "NTFS",
        "size": 249464614912,
        "used": 149687517184,
        "use": 60.00350680468374,
        "mount": "G:"
    }
]
```

Component Script:

```js
export default {
  name: "DISK",
  props: ["diskinfo"],
  watch: {
    diskinfo: function () {
      if (typeof this.diskinfo !== "undefined") {
        // convert to GB
        this.diskinfo.forEach((disk) => {
          disk.used = (disk.used / 1073741824).toFixed(0);
          disk.size = (disk.size / 1073741824).toFixed(0);
        });
        // remove if < 1 gb
        this.diskinfo.filter((disk) => disk.size === "0"); // Not filtering
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: I think you need to look up the definition for [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Pay particular attention to the _return value_

Comment: Sigh... simple oversight. thank you. Now I think I have an infinite loop since I am changing my prop, which triggers my watch method again, but I can look into this separately. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not be modifying a prop value. This is a Vue anti-pattern
2. [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is about deciding what stays, not what goes so if you want to remove elements with `size === 0`, you should use a `size > 0` comparison
3. You aren't doing anything with the return value of `Array.prototype.filter()` so of course no changes will be persisted

I don't know what you're doing with the `diskinfo` prop in this component but the typical way to handle something like this is with a computed property

```js
export default {
  name: "DISK",
  props: { diskinfo: Array },
  computed: {
    formattedDiskInfo () {
      return this.diskinfo.map(di => ({
        ...di,
        used: (di.used / 1073741824).toFixed(0),
        size: (di.size / 1073741824).toFixed(0)
      })).filter(({ size }) => size > 0)
    }
  }
}
```

In your template, you would use the `formattedDiskInfo` array instead of the `diskinfo` prop.

Comment: Oh, I forgot diskinfo is a prop. I think the better solution on this question is use computed too and we can do better than this. If he pass the prop with `.sync` the computed can write like this `computed: { diskinfo: { get() { return this.diskinfo }, set(val) { this.$emit('update:diskinfo', val.filter((disk) => disk.size === "0")) } }} `

Comment: @Cyrbuzz depends what OP's doing with it. I get the feeling this is for display purposes only in which case there's no need to set any of the changes permanently

Comment: @Phil is correct, this is for display purposes only. Worked perfectly. Learned a lot (new to Vue and not proficient with JS as I am with other langs). Thanks to both of you either way.

Comment: @Ned have a read of this part of the docs if you're interested in why I called it an anti-pattern ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 0):

Filter return a new one:

```
a = [1,2,3]

a.filter((b) => b < 2) // return [1] but a is still [1,2,3]
```

So you can do this:

```
this.diskinfo = this.diskinfo.filter((disk) => disk.size === "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Phill and Cyrbuzz said, the `filter` function returns the filtered array so you have to change this:

```
this.diskinfo.filter((disk) => disk.size === "0");
```

To this:

```
this.diskinfo = this.diskinfo.filter((disk) => disk.size === "0");
```

Comment: How is this different to @Cyrbuzz's answer (which you have quoted)?

Comment: It's not different. I just wanted to reinforce tthat @Cyrbuzz's answer was correct and hes answer did not deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: Then you should simply give it an upvote instead of writing a duplicate answer